# Inline editor for VF not showing despite having development mode and show view state enabled in user detail

Tags: visualforce, development-mode

New to VF here... I have dev mode and show view state in dev mode checked in my user detail page - however I cannot see the inline VF editor when I navigate to my Visualforce pages.

Comment: You did all correct change your browser to Chrome if not also try to switch to VS CODE as this is not an elegant way of coding or use developer console.

Comment: Thank you. I agree, many tutorials guide you towards using inline however I will use an IDE instead.